# What is meant by outsiders?

Tags: c#, class, public

[image: Click Here to see Picture]

I Started Learning C# and it confuses me with term 'outsiders'. Are outsiders some unauthorized people to our code?

Comment: Out of scope...?

Comment: Please, do not share code as an images

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski as a text then? I will take care of it in future

Comment: @Voyar yes, as text and code, others can easily copy it and reproduce. Your current question is about expnanation only, but for future it'll make sense

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I just checked my profile after a long time of inactivity and found that my previous question which was the same was put in closed state by You and another member. Kindly can you give me reason for that? I will look forward to make improvements

Comment: @Voyar I'm curious now. Why you posted the same question again?

Comment: @Voyar please, refer to these help topics https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example They give you all information how to ask a good and clear question, that others can solve and help you

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala haha i didn't knew about that cause i was inactive for a long time

Answer (score 4):

It is not C# jargon, but it refers to **any entity that is not the object**.
In this specific case, outsiders might be the factory that creates the player or other entities of the game.

In general you want to grant access to specified resources only to a selected few. This **maintains the code cleaner** (as you force using specific accesses you appositely designed) and **ensures the flow is followed** (imagine that when setting the score you also want to update other variables of `Player`, if someone modified the variable directly, the side effects would be bypassed).

The whole situation becomes even more critical when you are writing a library for others: you want to encapsulate the internal variables as much as possible and not allow others to have "free access" to everything, as they might tamper with important stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Outsiders is any other code outside of **this** object. So when you set variable as private, only code in **this** object can change it. That way you force any other code outside **this** class to modify score only by calling setScore method, and not directly accessing it.